# List unhashable error?

Tags: python, list, hash, dictionary

actuals and peaks are both lists of lists of integers.

In my code, I attempted to make a dictionary from lists of integers to lists of lists of integers as follows:

```
mapping={}
for a in actuals:
    mapping[a]=[v for v in peaks if v[0]==a[0]]
```

It returned, however, the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What might have gone wrong?

Comment: what is actuals? Is it a nested list?

Comment: You can't use lists as keys in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `a` is of type list (`actuals` being a list of lists). You are trying to assign a key to a dictionary to a `list` which is not possible. you have to come up with some other key, which is hashable.

Answer (score 0):

if each `a` is a list you are not going to change, you can make a tuple out of it:

```
mapping={}
for a in actuals:
    mapping[tuple(a)]=[v for v in peaks if v[0]==a[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys of a dictionary must implement `__hash__()` and these function must return a value that doesn't change if the object change and should, on the other hand, compute the hash value depending on the object's contents. Because the contents of a list can change it doesn't implement `__hash__()`.